# How can I make multiple API calls with the same key

Tags: json, api

I'm working on my Project and currently I have one API call to spoonacular's search by recipe GET request. I want to add the search by video GET Request but I seem to having problems getting both to render at once into the DOM. How can I fix this issue?

```
const apikey = '';
const urls = { search:'https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch',
videos: 'https://api.spoonacular.com/food/videos/search'
};


function queryParams(params) {
    const queryItems = Object.keys(params).map(key=>`${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(params[key])}`)
    return queryItems.join('&');
}
```

///render results

```
function getRecipe(tacos,maxResults){
  const params ={
    query: tacos,
    number: maxResults,
  };


  const queryString = queryParams(params)
  const url = urls+'?'+queryString +'&apiKey='+ apikey;

  console.log(url);


  fetch(url)
  fetch(urls.search)
  .then(response =>{
    if(response.ok){
      return response.json();
    }
    throw new Error(response.statusText);
  })
  .then(responseJson => displayResults(responseJson))
  .catch(err =>{
    $('#js-error-message').text(`Something went wrong: ${err.message}`);
  });
}
```

Comment: `const url = urls+'?'+queryString +'&apiKey='+ apikey;` urls is an object with two properties, what are you trying to do with this intruction?

Answer (score 0):

Your `urls` is an object containing two strings. You need to treat it as such and make two separate calls.

You should have a `fetch(urls.search)` and `fetch(urls.videos)` call, each with their own response chain.

I'm not sure this code is doing what you think it is:

`const url = urls+'?'+queryString +'&apiKey='+ apikey;`

You'll need to append the `queryString` and `apiKey` to each string within `urls` separately. Something like

```
const searchUrl = urls.search+'?'+queryString +'&apiKey='+ apikey;
const videosUrl = urls.videos+'?'+queryString +'&apiKey='+ apikey;
```

Comment: Ok. I added a get video functions alongside the get result function and added fetch call for the both of the strings and appended them to their individual . I'm still having problems getting to render both the video and the image. Where am i going wrong with this?

Comment: @NateNkumbu I'm not sure, you should post your updated code

Comment: ```function displayVideos(responseJson){
  $('#results-videos').empty();
  $('.js-error').empty();
  for(let i=0; i < responseJson.videos.length; i++){
    $('#results-videos').append(
      `<li><h3><a"${responseJson.videos[i].youTubeId}">${responseJson.videos[i].title}</a> ${responseJson.videos[i].lenght}</h3><img src='${responseJson.videos[i].thumbnail}'></li>`
    )};
    $('#results').removeClass('hidden');
```
I also get this returned via console.log

```
https://api.spoonacular.com/food/videos/search?query=tacos&number=5&apiKey=65fce80e490c4cb58c8fdd77edc4677d
```

Comment: @NateNkumbu I do not know what your problem is but you should update your original post with the new code formatted correctly. It's hard to make sense of it like this.